# print the all <loc> tag values using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class URL {

    WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void test_URL() throws InterruptedException{

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://www.proptiger.com/city-image-sitemap.xml");

        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("loc"));
        System.out.println(links.size());

        for(int i=0; i<links.size();i++){
            //Thread.sleep(200);
            System.out.println(i+ "."+links.get(i).getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Suddenly It is stop execution. It is not given all  tag values.
I want all links in this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it worked for me perfectly

```
   driver.get("url");

    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'text') and contains(text(),'https')]"));
    System.out.println(links.size());

    for(int i=0; i<links.size();i++){
        //Thread.sleep(200);
        System.out.println(i+ "."+links.get(i).getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Selenium does not handle XML**. It only handles HTML. There are various plugins for xml parsing that might help you.

There is a solution of your problem on stackoverflow. Please have a look on this - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8445497

Answer (score 0):

You can handle XML by Selenium using a different approach. Try this xpath : //*[name()='loc'] for finding all the  tag values

**Try this code:**

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://www.proptiger.com/city-image-sitemap.xml");

        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[name()='loc']"));
        System.out.println(links.size());

        for(int i=0; i<links.size();i++){
            //Thread.sleep(200);
            System.out.println(i+ "."+links.get(i).getText());
        }
```

Comment: This won't work. You will not be able to get values from tagName loc. Please Try.

Comment: I just tried and I am able to get the text of the tag name <loc>

Comment: System.out.println(i+ "."+links.get(i).getText()); // I am only getting value of i + "."

Comment: I request you to please try the exact code given by me. I have executed the code on my machine.

Comment: You have to fetch links by using the xpath: List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[name()='loc']"));