# trying to update the same XML file with a new XML nodes using the tag name

Tags: java, xml

I am creating a simple java function to update/re-write the value of an xml file.
I am able to pick the XML file from the system resource, after updating the file and re-writing, the value of the node never gets changes.

Here are my snippets:

```
String filePath = ABS_PATH + File.separator + "fields.xml";

File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
try {
    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    //update Element value
    updateElementValue(doc);

    //write the updated document to file or console
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(ABS_PATH
                 + File.separator + "fields.xml")); // updating/re-writing the same file
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    System.out.println("XML file updated successfully");

} catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException | TransformerException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

//method to show the update element value
private static void updateElementValue(Document doc) {
    NodeList employees = doc.getElementsByTagName("NO");
    Element emp = null;
    //loop for each
    for (int i = 0; i < employees.getLength(); i++) {
        emp = (Element)employees.item(i);
        Node name = emp.getElementsByTagName("String").item(0).getFirstChild();
        name.setNodeValue(name.getNodeValue().toUpperCase());
    }

}
```

sample of the xml file

```
  <Document xmlns="http://hello.com/schema/public/services/platform" Id="1">
  <Fields>
    <Field FieldName="NO">
      <String>Demo</String>
    </Field>
    <Field FieldName="TYPE">
      <String>Zada</String>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
```

who is motivated enough to assist

Comment: `NodeList employees = doc.getElementsByTagName("NO");` will return an empty list, since you do not have elements with **tag** "NO".

Comment: PLEASE make it an answer

Comment: Posted as you wished.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following statement:

```
 NodeList employees = doc.getElementsByTagName("NO");
```

It will return an empty list, since your XML does not have any nodes with "NO" as a **tag**.

```
 <Field FieldName="NO">
```

Statements inside your loop iterating through the list will never be executed. You node will not be updated.

Your elements with tag `Field` have attribute `FieldName`. One of them has **attribute value** of "NO". So you need to find it.

See if [How to get specific XML elements with specific attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445408/how-to-get-specific-xml-elements-with-specific-attribute-value) gives you enough guidance.

You can do it with a loop  as well.

```
NodeList employees = doc.getElementsByTagName("Field");
for (int i = 0; i < employees.getLength(); i++) {
     emp = (Element)employees.item(i);
     if ("NO".equals(emp.item(i).getAttribute("FieldName"))) {
           // do your stuff
     }
}
```

The above is not tested.

Comment: thanks, but how do I get this - FieldName="NO" to get this value - Demo and update it. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Are you familiar with [XPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html)?

Comment: Well.. Either you familiarize yourself or use a library like [JSOUP.](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByAttributeValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: I followed thru this tutorial, as it has same structure with mine, but no head-way
https://www.journaldev.com/901/modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser

Comment: OK. Posted it using only functionality you already should be familiar with.